# Select first item in table view in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

If count of the Array that tableview is using is 1 then how to select the first row in the table i used the following code it is selecting but not navigating to next screen

```
     NSIndexPath * ip =[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    [npTable selectRowAtIndexPath:ip animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to use some delegate methods for uitabelview

1. you have to add UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate.
2. You have to add the delegate method of uitabelview i.e)

Add delegate method as below.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //here you have to write the code for to navigate next screen.
    sample *sampleobject=[[sample alloc]init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:sampleobject animated:YES];
}
```

that's it enjoy now u can naviagte to another page..

Comment: if array count is 1 it should select first as default

Answer (score 0):

This only highlights the table cell. You would need to call the code which would appear in your tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath method or alternatively you could call it yourself like:

```
NSIndexPath * ip =[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
[self tableView: npTable didSelectRowAtIndexPath: ip];
```

Comment: you might want to include the code inside your didSelectRowAtIndexPath method in your question so we can see whats going on...